gasの処理速度は何に依存するのでしょうか
gasの処理にはgoogle側のサーバーリソースが割り当てられてそこでスクリプトが処理されています。
同じ処理でも実行速度にかなりムラ（同じデータ量で完了まで2倍以上時間がかかる等）があり原因を探しています。
処理に割り当てられるサーバーリソースが逼迫すると処理時間も遅くなるのではないかと考えるのですが、
以下のパターンは当てはまるのでしょうか？
①GoogleWorkSpace内のアカウントでそれぞれ別のgasが実行されている状態
　→　WorkSpace単位でサーバーリソースが割り当てられていると考えると、同じ時間帯にgasが実行されると遅くなるのは理解できます。
②スクリプトファイル内でそれぞれgasが実行されている状態
　→　スクリプトファイル単位でリソースが割り当てられているとなると、AppScriptの1ファイル内でそれぞれ独立した関数が動いていると処理が遅くなる。
体感としては②でトリガーで定期処理や他の処理が動いているときは何となく実行している処理も遅くなるような気がするのですが、サーバーの割当について仕様はあるのでしょうか？


同じ処理でも実行速度にかなりムラ（同じデータ量で完了まで2倍以上時間がかかる等）があり原因を探しています。

同じ処理でもアカウントに割り振られているトークンなどによってトークンが復活するまでなど、処理が遅くなっていることが考えられます。
GAS(Google Apps Script)の制限と割当(日本語訳あり) 

ご回答ありがとうございます！割り振られているトークンの意味が理解できていないのですが、他の処理実行中に実行開始すると待ちが発生するようなイメージなのでしょうか。

https://qiita.com/kakakaori830/items/84a7dcba2d6119ed320a
できることの制限が詳細に決まっていますので、閲覧いただくのがいいかと思います

ありがとうございます！制限については承知しているところなのですが、制限を超えると実行ができなくなる又は中断されるという認識でして処理速度には影響ないのかと思っております。制限が近づくと処理速度も遅くなってくるとかなら納得はできるのですが。

例えば同時実行数の制限が30なので実行数が27,8とかになってくると割り当てられるサーバーのCPU使用率やメモリの使用率が上がって処理も遅くなる…のようなことは起こり得るのでしょうか。

1人のアカウントにあり当てられるAPIの実行上限などがある
1日にメール送れるのは何通までねみたいな制限があるのでその上限に足したら復活するまで待つしかないです


サーバーの割当について仕様はあるのでしょうか？

私が調べた限りでは、このあたりの仕様は公開されていないようです。

同じ処理でも実行速度にかなりムラ（同じデータ量で完了まで2倍以上時間がかかる等）があり原因を探しています。

考えられる要因としては、割り当てられるリソースが占有リソースではない。ということではないでしょうか？
論理区画が割り当てられたとしてもリソースは共有ということは、クラウドサービスではあります。
ただし、クォーターがアカウント単位で設定されているということは、アカウント単位でリソースが割り当てられているのではないかと思われます。

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas


ご回答ありがとうございます！やはりそう考えるのが自然ですよね。ただスクリプトの処理が遅くなるとWorkSpace内のどのアカウントでも同じスクリプトを実行しても速度は遅くなる印象でしたのでWorkSpace単位でも割り当てられているリソースがあり、その中でさらにアカウントにリソースの割り当てがあるのかと思ったりしました。

「WorkSpace単位でも割り当てられているリソースがあり、その中でさらにアカウントにリソースの割り当てがあるのかと」そうかもしれませんね。ちなみに、どのようなスクリプトで再現されるのでしょうか？スプレッドシート等に対して処理を行っている場合、そちらがボトルネックになっている可能性もあると思い。

ご親切にありがとうございます。
スクリプト自体は特に変わったことはしておらず、スプレッドシートからgetValueで値を読み取って比較処理を行ってsetValueで書き出すような処理になります（全容は多岐に渡るので記述しきれずすいません）1回のスクリプトで比較する処理は1万回以上になるので基本に習い1行ずつsetValueするのではなくmapにpushして最後に一括で書き出すようにしています。
仰るとおり要因が色々考えられ
１：スクリプトの問題、２：スプレッドシートの問題、３：gasサーバーの問題
他にもスプレッドシートにアクセスしている人数、スプレッドシートの容量等など関係ないと思いつつも考え出すとたくさん出てきて問題の切り分けをしたく今回質問させていただきました。
まだ結論は出ていないのですが、同じデータ量のシートのみを切り出して試したところ安定してきたような気がするのでスプレッドシート側で使われている関数がなにか影響しているような気がしてきています。
